# Server 2012 Mapped Drives using Samba and Linux User Accounts

Tags: linux, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, samba

Afternoon all,

I am in the process of building an Active Directory Domain to be placed into our workplace.

I have come to the point of setting up the shared drives that each of the staff members use and am a little lost, I am currently using a Linux server to serve Samba shares, each staff member then has a username and password for the share and is part of a Linux group that allows them access to different folders.  Currently this is working great and I am able to restrict the users to the folders they need and not show all of them.

Moving on to Server 2012 AD and I am looking at the drive mapping through the GPO, I have noticed that the "Connect AS" feature has been remove for security, this is fine.  The issue I have at the moment is maintaining the same login details that are provided by the Linux Samba box when mapping to the AD.

Am I right in thinking that if I want to maintain the users login and password and groups allocation that I will have to create a separate GPO for each user?

Am I going about this the wrong way?  Is there a way of serving the Samba shares securely so as not to allow people without the correct group membership to access them and at the same time reduce the amount of GPO's I have to create?

Cheers in advance.

Comment: You can assign UIDs to users in AD and map them to Unix accounts.  We have this working with RHEL, but I've only got involved in the AD side of things.  The RHEL guide is here: https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=0ahUKEwil2q2BkYTSAhUsDsAKHZ4TDbYQFgg8MAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Faccess.redhat.com%2Fdocumentation%2Fen-US%2FRed_Hat_Enterprise_Linux%2F7%2Fpdf%2FWindows_Integration_Guide%2FRed_Hat_Enterprise_Linux-7-Windows_Integration_Guide-en-US.pdf&usg=AFQjCNG-Ziou24Rdq-ODPuuEAhBAn3cvNA

Comment: @SimonCatlin sorry for the late reply, really busy.  Thanks for the information, I ended up taking a different route and using iSCSI from a NAS drive.

Comment: @030 Please don't edit my post and remove the greeting and thanks from it, especially when you don't even leave a comment to say why you have deleted them.